# How can I check how often my readthedocs page was hit?

Tags: read-the-docs

I'm hosting a project ob github and use Sphinx and RTD to automatically convert and display my docs at RTD.

How do I add a page hit counter to my RTD page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Google Analytics to monitor your RTD documentation.

Here's the page in the RTD documentation:
[Enabling Google Analytics on your Project](http://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/google-analytics.html)

Quote from the link:

> Read the Docs has native support for Google Analytics. You can enable it by:
>
> - Going to **Admin > Advanced Settings** in your project.
> - Fill in the **Analytics code** heading with your Google Tracking ID (example `UA-123456674-1`)
>
> Once your documentation rebuilds it will include your Analytics tracking code and start sending data. Google Analytics usually takes 60 minutes, and sometimes can take up to a day before it starts reporting data.